# Get current date In Offline Mode

Tags: ios, date, offline

How can I get the actual date if the device date is not accurate?

Is there any other way to maintain the date locally without network?

It would be great if any one suggests the exact idea behind this.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. If you can't access an NTP server or an external server to request the time you have to rely on the device, it would be impossible to do otherwise. You can track how much time has passed since your app has opened although the only reference point for time is that set on the device.

The important question is why an accurate date is crucial to your app?