# Is it possible to get the exact correct date and time (not device time) in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm having a problem in my app. I want to get the exact correct date and time even though the user changed the device date and time. Is this possible to achieve if the device is not connected to the internet? By the way, here is the code that I tried.

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
{
    TimeZoneInfo currentTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Asia/Singapore");

    DisplayTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, currentTimeZone);
    return true;
});
```

Comment: If you can't get the time from a trusted, external, network source then you are stuck.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483212/get-current-date-in-offline-mode

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty hard to achieve. You need to fallback to GPS datetime or carrier datetime. A little bit of digging lead to this [xamarin discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14158/get-date-by-gps)

```
            protected override void OnResume()
            {
                base.OnResume();
                locationManager = GetSystemService (Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
                locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.GpsProvider, 1000, 1, this);

            }

        public void OnLocationChanged (Android.Locations.Location location)
        {
            Log.Debug (tag, "Location changed");
            DateTime dt = FromUnixTime(location.Time);
            txtStatusGPS.Text = dt.ToString ();
        }

        public DateTime FromUnixTime(long unixTime)
        {
             var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
             return epoch.AddSeconds(unixTime);
        }
```

Other suggestions are to store the time locally and monitor time changes from the device and other workarounds, but nothing that works without problems (especially in precision).